# How do I debug MSpec tests in MonoDevelop/Xamarin Studio?

Tags: macos, unit-testing, testing, monodevelop, mspec

Using MonoDevelop 5.x on OSX, I have some failing unit tests using Machine.Specifications that I would like to debug through to find the specific issue that's causing the failure. Is there a way to debug MSpec tests through MonoDevelop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run MSpec code through custom commands allowing you to debug through your tests directly through MonoDevelop:

1. Go to your project options
2. Select `Run > Custom Commands`
3. Select `Execute` under the dropdown menu
4. For the command, browse and select your mspec runner
5. Select `Target File`
6. For the working directory, select `Project Directory`

[image: Custom Command Screenshot]

You should now have a command that looks like `../path/to/mspec-clr.exe ${TargetFile}`

You should now be able to place breakpoints in your test code, and start your tests with `Start Debugging Item` or running in debug mode.